# Need help for locking down linux desktop

Tags: permissions, security

Good morning all.

So I work with a disabled guy and he has a computer. This guy asked for assistance, I put windows xp on his computer and I discovered that he loves deleting files (he managed to delete the system making it impossible to boot...)

I decided to try ubuntu, it will be  a better solution than windows XP I'm sure he will love the colors... I want to lock down his account to absolutely block pornography access, block any way that he can delete applications or install new ones.

I also want to lock the desktop so that he can't delete the icons or change wallpaper or whatever... otherwise he will empty the desktop change the wallpaper and come again and again.

It will be extremely nice if some one could have the patience to solve my problem.
thanks in advance.

Edit: So the thing if he find a way changing the wallpaper he won't be abble to put it back and will probably delete or watever... and in the desktop as i know you have the shortcuts for the applications like google chrome... if he delete I don't even know were linux put the applications once installed ^^'. and is there any "parental control" ? Edit: thanks :)

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't have anything on the desktop, so there won't be anything to empty, and I can see nothing bad in changing the wallpaper. It's very hard to read your question, so I am not exactly sure what you are asking.

Comment: Hello thank you for awsering so the thing if he find a way changing   the wallpaper he won't be abble to put it back and will probably delete or watever... and in the desktop as i know you have the shortcuts for the applications like google chrome... if he delete I don't even know were linux put the applications once installed ^^'. and is there any "parental control" ?          Edit: thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please provide additional information only by editing your question and not within a comment. Comments might/will eventually be deleted and so your information would get lost.

Comment: all right good to know edited I will avoid this kind of mistake next time ^^'

Comment: There is no way to delete the default wallpapers in Ubuntu without admin access. They are all owned by root, and are located in /usr/share/backgrounds/. Even if he finds the place, he won't be able to delete them, unless you give him the password. Same goes for application launchers. Again, there aren't any on the desktop by default (Google Chrome is not even installed), all the launchers appear in the Dash, and there is no delete button there - in short, Ubuntu is not Windows. As for parental control, check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ParentalControls.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for all this awnsers I think the problem is solved but I do no how to put as solved

Comment: There is no way to delete system stuff in Ubuntu **as a user**. That means the OS should stay up and stable, no matter what your user attempts. Then again, the same is true for XP. Non-admin users should not be able to corrupt XP on an NTFS partition either. (if you give them admin or use FAT which supports no rights then that is a different case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pessulus, it's one of linux's lockdown editor(not installed by default though). Add it using synaptic package manager and run it in a terminal by typing pessulus. A GUI app based will open up and you'll be able to choose what you can lock down. 
Hope that helps.
-EHS

Answer (score 0):

Once you have installed the Ubuntu you manage the appearance of icon bar like it can stay hidden until you scroll over the area where its hidden (left right or bottom).

Comment: It stays on left hand side of screen, as soon as you touch your mouse cursor to left wall of screen it appears.